# Without using beta function, for what $p$ does $\int_0^\infty \frac{\log(x)}{1+x^p} dx$ converge?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

**Question:**

> For what $p$ does $\int_0^\infty \frac{\log(x)}{1+x^p} dx$ converge?

Is there a simpler solution to this integral than approaching it via the beta function (which I have not yet learned but have seen it solved this way)? Specifically, can someone put forward a solution that looks at the integrand at its "bad" areas where it might fail to converge, thus causing the entire integral to fail to converge?

First, I notice that if $p>0$ then $x^p \approx 0$ near $x=0$. Or if $p<0$, then $x^p \to \infty$ around $x=0$.

Comment: Not an answer, but perhaps a useful heuristic: $\log$ grows more slowly than any polynomial. So far from $0$, we can bound $\log x$ by $x^{\epsilon}$, and so we can try to see for what $p$ we get $x^\epsilon/(1+x^p)$ integrable. This function is basically $1/x^{p-\epsilon}$ far from $0$, and this is integrable when $p-\epsilon >  1$, i.e. $p > 1 + \epsilon$. Since $\epsilon>0$ is arbitrary we can guess that $p>1$ is probably at least necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First consider the integral over $[0,1]$.

For all $p \in \mathbb{R}$,

$$-\frac{\log(x)}{1 + x^p}\leqslant -\log(x),$$

and

$$\int_0^1 -\log(x) \,dx=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\int_\epsilon^1 -\log(x) \,dx = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0}[x-x \log(x)]|_\epsilon^1 \\= \lim_{\epsilon \to 0}[1 - \epsilon+ \epsilon\log(\epsilon)]= 1.$$

Therefore, the integral over $[0,1]$converges for all $p \in \mathbb{R}$ by the comparison test .

The integral over $[1,\infty)$ converges for $p > 2$ by the comparison test since

$$\frac{\log(x)}{1 + x^p}\leqslant x^{-(p-1)},$$

and $\int_1^{\infty}x^{-(p-1)}\,dx$ converges for $p > 2$.

Also,

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\log(x)}{(1+x^p)x^{-p}}= \lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\log(x)}{1+x^{-p}}= \infty.$$

By the limit comparison test, the integral over $[1,\infty)$ diverges for $p \leqslant 1$ since $\int_1^{\infty}x^{-p}\,dx$ diverges for $p \leqslant 1.$

For $1 < p \leq 2$, use

$$\frac{\log(x)}{2x^p} \leqslant \frac{\log(x)}{1+x^p} \leqslant \frac{\log(x)}{x^p},$$

and compare with

$$\int_1^{\infty} \frac{\log(x)}{x^p} \, dx = \int_0^{\infty} xe^{(1-p)x} \, dx$$

which converges for $p > 1$.